# To "pull over" a cruller?

Tags: meaning-in-context

According to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruller), "a cruller is a deep-fried pastry popular in the US and Canada often made from a rectangle of dough, with a cut made in the middle that allows it to be pulled over and through itself producing twists in the sides of the pastry."

What is the meaning of pulling over a cruller?

I have found 2 definitions for "pull over":

1. To bring a vehicle to a stop at a curb or at the side of a road.
2. To force (a motorist or a vehicle) to stop at a curb or at the side of a road.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the phrase "pull over".

The quote you give is "pull **over and through itself**". It's literally pulling the dough, so that it forms a twist.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Could someone help me understand the meaning of "through itself" in this context? The closest phrases I have found are "in itself/of itself", but they are used for emphasizing that what you are saying about one particular thing is true without even considering anything else. Thank you !

Comment: You're really overthinking these. They're not phrases, they're the plain meaning of the words. Make a hole and pull the dough through the hole.